# css nth-child formula generator

Tags: css, css-selectors

Well I am trying to figure out a formula for my nth-child selector.

And I was wondering if there was something like a formula generator.

Enter the number of the elements I wish to target. 
And out comes the formula

I am trying to find the formula for the following numbers: 1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11, ect.

So skip every third element.

**EDIT**

I had to skip the first two, so I went with

```
li:nth-child(3n+4), li:nth-child(3n+5)
```

Comment: Well, looking for reverse, enter which I want and get formula. Found something like http://nth-calculator.com/ but it doesn't find a single formula, but gives a different one for every number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:nth-child(3n + 1)` and `:nth-child(3n + 2)`.

```css
ul li:nth-child(3n + 1), ul li:nth-child(3n + 2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Some math:

```
{1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11,...}
= {1,4,7,10,...} ∪ {2,5,8,11,...}
= {3n+1 : n ∈ ℕ*} ∪ {3n+2 : n ∈ ℕ*}
```

<sup>Where `ℕ* = ℕ ∪ {0}`</sup>

Therefore, you can use

```css
:nth-child(3n+1), :nth-child(3n+2) {
    /* Code */
}
```

Comment: Can you direct me to where I can read more on this type of math.

Comment: @PrivatMamtora Try [Set (mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) at Wikipedia.

Comment: one of your formulas should be 3n+2